# Simulation of an alien population

Tags: python, programming-challenge, numpy, simulation, markov-chain

#### Background

I've come across a puzzle [(Problem 10 from this list of sample interview questions)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/20-challenging-job-interview-puzzles-which-every-analyst-solve-atleast/):

> One day, an alien comes to Earth. Every day, each alien does one of four things, each with equal probability to:
>
> - Kill himself
> - Do nothing
> - Split himself into two aliens (while killing himself)
> - split himself into three aliens (while killing himself)
>
> What is the probability that the alien species eventually dies out entirely?

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve the problem theoretically. Then I moved on to simulate it with a basic Markov Chain and Monte Carlo simulation in mind.

*This was not asked to me in an interview. I learned the problem from a friend, then found the link above while searching for mathematical solutions.*

#### Reinterpreting the question

We start with the number of aliens `n = 1`. `n` has a chance to not change, be decremented by `1`, be incremented by `1`, and be incremented by `2`, %25 for each. If `n` is incremented, i.e. aliens multiplied, we repeat this procedure for `n` times again. This corresponds to each alien will do its thing again. I have to put an upper limit though, so that we stop simulating and avoid a crash. `n` is likely to increase and we're looping `n` times again and again.

If aliens somehow go extinct, we stop simulating again since there's nothing left to simulate.

After `n` reaches zero or the upper limit, we also record the population (it will be either zero or some number `>= max_pop`).

I repeat this many times and record every result. At the end, number of zeros divided by total number of results should give me an approximation.

#### The code

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

pop_max = 100
iter_max = 100000

results = np.zeros(iter_max, dtype=int)

for i in range(iter_max):
    n = 1
    while n > 0 and n < pop_max:
        for j in range(n):
            x = randint(1, 4)
            if x == 1:
                n = n - 1
            elif x == 2:
                continue
            elif x == 3:
                n = n + 1
            elif x == 4:
                n = n + 2
    results[i] = n

print( np.bincount(results)[0] / iter_max )
```

`iter_max` and `pop_max` can be changed indeed, but I thought if there is 100 aliens, the probability that they go extinct would be negligibly low. This is just a guess though, I haven't done anything to calculate a (more) proper upper limit for population.

This code gives promising results, fairly close to the real answer which is approximately %41.4.

#### Some outputs

```
> python aliens.py
0.41393
> python aliens.py
0.41808
> python aliens.py
0.41574
> python aliens.py
0.4149
> python aliens.py
0.41505
> python aliens.py
0.41277
> python aliens.py
0.41428
> python aliens.py
0.41407
> python aliens.py
0.41676
```

#### Aftermath

I'm okay with the results but I can't say the same for the time this code takes. It takes around 16-17 seconds :)

How can I improve the speed? How can I optimize loops (especially the `while` loop)? Maybe there's a much better approach or better models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some obvious possible simplifications for elegance, if not necessarily for speed.

The `while` condition should be written as a double-ended inequality:

```
while 0 < n < pop_max:
    …
```

The variable `j` is unused.  The convention is to use `_` as the name of a "throwaway" variable.

The `if`-`elif` chain can be eliminated with a smarter `randint()` call:

```
for j in range(n):
    n += randint(-1, 2)
```

NumPy is overkill here, when all you want to know whether the population went extinct.  The built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function can do the counting for you.

Each simulation run is independent.  I'd put the code in a function for readability.

```
from random import randint

def population(pop_max=100):
    n = 1
    while 0 < n < pop_max:
        for _ in range(n):
            n += randint(-1, 2)
    return n

iterations = 100000
print(sum(population() == 0 for _ in range(iterations)) / iterations)
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy has a function to generate a random array, this might be faster than generating a random number within the inner loop.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

You can also try generating a larger 32 or 64-bit number, and shifting and masking the whole time to get 2 random bits. However, this is a bit far-fetched.

Comment: Depending on the platform (and especially in python) working with native machine words is faster even if it seems wasteful to only use 2-3 bits out of 64 or 32.